# Trouble with cp command for directories

Tags: shell

I'm trying to use the cp function to do copy directories:

src/1/b
src/2/d
src/3/c
src/4/a
src/5/e
then the copying should result in

tgt/a/4
tgt/b/1
tgt/c/3
tgt/d/2
tgt/e/5
I tried to use the 'basename' function as well as 'cp dir1/*dir2'. With the basename, do I make a loop to find every directory or is there a recursive builtin? Also tried the 'cp-r' recursive copy function. But nothing so far has worked.

Comment: Please provide the commands you already tried without success.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: mkdir tgt;
cp -r src tgt

Comment: @drsnark using mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `tmp` folder that will hols the SOURCE list of files, yo can readjust:

```
cat tmp

result:
src/1/b
src/2/d
src/3/c
src/4/a
src/5/e
```

from here, I echo out the command, but you can remove `echo` and it will execute, if this output seems correct:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat tmp |while read z
do
  echo cp "$z" "tgt/$(echo "$z"|cut -d/ -f 3)/$(echo "$z"|cut -d/ -f 2)"
done

result:
cp src/1/b tgt/b/1
cp src/2/d tgt/d/2
cp src/3/c tgt/c/3
cp src/4/a tgt/a/4
cp src/5/e tgt/e/5
```

you can also add parameters to `cp` as you see fit. But first test with the `echo` command, then execute :)